# SSIS - XML file empty after rename task

Tags: xml, ssis

So, I have this XML file (test.xml) with a lot of data in it. I read the XML file and move it from folder A to Folder B. Yet, somehow when it gets moved to Folder B, the XML file is totally empty.

This is what it says in the Progress monitor:

```
[File System Task] Information: File or directory "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\test.xml" was deleted.
```

The file itself does reach his destination, but it is just an empty XML file when it gets there.

I have no idea why it does this. I have double checked it and the file system task clearly says "move file".

Any ideas?

Comment: A delete wouldn't empty the file.. it would delete it. Is `Desktop` folder A or Folder B in this case? Perhaps some other part of your process is doing this.

Comment: I think I found it. My target folder (param) had one \ too much at the end. Deleting that one character made the file move correctly. No idea how it could affect it like that, but deleting that character in my parameter fixed it.

Comment: Perhaps for completeness could you describe what you found as an answer - it will be valuable for other people with the same problem. If not... thanks for returning with a solution anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. For people who might have the same problem as me in the future:

I made use of a Project parameter called `Targetfolder`. This one had as value the path to my desktop. This should have been `C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\` for me, but I mistyped it with an extra backslash at the end: `C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\\`.

I don't know why, but this caused the XML to move to the targetfolder in an empty state. Deleting the last backslash from the parameter fixed it.

(Also a special thank you for the people who wanted to help)